# Run methods in Parallel using Reactive

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, system.reactive

Halo there all, I was looking for a solution with RX framework. My C# 4.0 class is going to call 2 different methods and to save the time, I want to do it in parallel. Is there any way to run 2 different methods in parallel using Reactive Framework ? Not only run those 2 methods parallel, but also one should wait for other to complete and combine the both results. Example as shown below:

```
AccountClass ac = new AccountClass();    
string val1 = ac.Method1();  
bool val2 = ac.Method2();
```

How I can run these 2 methods run in parallel and waits each other to complete and combine the results together in the Subscription part ?

Comment: This is more of a `TPL`/`Parallel` question than Rx - there's no real need for "push-based" functionality here.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = Observable.Zip(
    Observable.Start(() => callMethodOne()),
    Observable.Start(() => callMethodTwo()),
    (one, two) => new { one, two });

result.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: This (or replacing `Zip` with `CombineLatest`) is probably the most straightforward answer, although I still maintain you don't *need* to use Rx for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [zip](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc43) method to achive needed behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;


string val1 = null;
bool val2 = false;

var actions = new List<Action>();

actions.Add(() =>
{
     val1 = ac.Method1();
});

actions.Add(() =>
{
     val2 = ac.Method2();
});


Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions(), actions.ToArray());

// alternative - using Parallel.ForEach:
// Parallel.ForEach(actions, action => action());

// rest of your code here.....
```

Helpful link:

http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/ParallelClass.html

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? It would be nice to have a comment from who did it

Answer (score -1):

Similar to [Rui Jarimba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203658/173099), but a bit more succinct;

```
        string val1 = null;
        bool val2 = false;

        Action action1 = () =>
        {
            val1 = ac.Method1();
        };

        Action action2 = () =>
        {
            val2 = ac.Method2();
        };

        Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions(), action1, action2);
```